# Custom TextField change settings at the time of creation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want all of  TextField to have small letters.and if I need to change to a larger one I could write inside the creation.But my code doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

**class ViewController: UIViewController**

```
 private let TextField: CustomTextField = { //LETTERS (no work)
        let textfield = CustomTextField() 
        textfield.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters 
        return textfield
    }()
private let TextField2: CustomTextField = { //letters (work)
    let textfield = CustomTextField() 
    return textfield
}()
```

**class CustomTextField: UITextField**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews() 
    self.autocapitalizationType = .none 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`layoutSubviews()` function is called after the initialization of your textFields. If you debug your code, you will see that `TextField.autocapitalizationType` will be set to `.allCharacters`. But after initialization of your object, `layoutSubviews()` will be called and `autocapitalizationType` will be set to `.none`. So you need to define the `self.autocapitalizationType = .none`  inside `init` of your `CustomTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the override of `layoutSubviews()` - as mentioned by Muhammed's answer, setting the `autocapitalizationType` here will overwrite your custom value as soon as `layoutSubviews()` is called.

Then, if you give your `CustomTextField` a custom initializer with a parameter for the capitalization type like this:

```
init(autocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationType = .none) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.autocapitalizationType = autocapitalizationType
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Then you can just initialize it all in one step like this, no closure required:

```
private let textField = CustomTextField(autocapitalizationType: .allCharacters)
```

If you don't want to set a type then you can leave the `CustomTextField()` parentheses empty since the initializer adds `.none` as a default.